# Run vstest.console.exe as Administrator From VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest

We have a build that runs some tests using vstest.console.exe. Even though the build agent has local admin rights. VSTest still fails as its not able the create an environment variable.

I have tried

Running the server as a local admin
Setting vstest.console.exe to run as administrator in the vstest.console.exe properties

If i run vstest.console.exe from the same account as the build agent, but elevate the command window to an administrator. This works fine.

Comment: Doesn't look like it can be done from the standard VSTS task.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) with runas Verb and check the result.